# choosing what XML data to display without attributes JS/XML

Tags: javascript, xml

So i want to choose what XML data to display (without using attributes) using Javascript. Here are the specifics about what i want to do:

XML

```
<channel>

  <item>
     <title>3.jpg</title>
     <link>images/clean/3-dirty.jpg</link>
  </item>

  <item>
     <title>4.jpg</title>
     <link>images/clean/4-dirty.jpg</link>
  </item>

<item>
     <title>5.jpg</title>
     <link>images/clean/4-clean.jpg</link>
  </item>

  <item>
     <title>6.jpg</title>
     <link>images/clean/4-dirty.jpg</link>
  </item>

... and the list goes on for ages.

</channel>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","xml/drc.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
document.write("<img src='");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("' alt='image' height='220px' width='260px' />");
}

</script>
```

How can i display images that only contains the word "dirty" or "clean" in the url?
I've tried using IndexOf() method but can't get it to work.

Comment: can you show how you used it? Did you use lower case `indexOf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```js
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
    var src = x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    if( src.indexOf("dirty") != -1 ) {
       document.write("<img src='");
       document.write(src);
       document.write("' alt='image' height='220px' width='260px' />");
    }
}
```

if it doesn't work, try this, too:

```js
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
    var src = x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var srcLower = src.toLowerCase();
    if( srcLower.indexOf("dirty") != -1 ) {
       document.write("<img src='");
       document.write(src);
       document.write("' alt='image' height='220px' width='260px' />");
    }
}
```

Comment: the image link can contain some uppercase letters( ex: DirTy) and if you want to take them too, you should use the second code ;)